# How to measure time of executation of each layer in CNNs

Tags: conv-neural-network

In convolutional neural network architectures for image classification (e.g. VGG or AlexNet) I would like to compare the time it takes to compute the result of each layer of the network while making a forward pass in test time (preferebly using Caffe).

In particular, I am interesteed how much time is spent on convolutional layers vs. fully connected layers.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to create two networks, one which only has the convolutional layers and one which only has the dense (fully connected) layers. Do a forward pass using the convolutional network, measure its time, pass the result (output of convolutional only network) into the fully connected network, do a forward pass and measure its time.

Answer (score 0):

so, what is you problem. `caffe time` did not work?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `class caffe::Timer` in [net.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/net.cpp) just for your test like this:

```
#include "caffe/util/benchmark.hpp" //use class caffe::Timer

Dtype Net<Dtype>::ForwardFromTo(int start, int end) {
  ... //Some original contents
  Timer timer;
  for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
    ...//Some original contents
    string layer_name = layers_[i]->layer_param().name(); //get layer name
    timer.Start();
    Dtype layer_loss = layers_[i]->Forward(bottom_vecs_[i], top_vecs_[i]);
    float forward_time = timer.MicroSeconds();
    LOG(ERROR) << layer_name << " consumes: " << forward_time << " microseconds during forward.";
    ...
  }
  return loss;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

every caffe layer has a forward and backward function in `src/caffe/layers` dir, for example `src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cpp` is cpu implementation, `src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cu` is the gpu implementation.So you need to add a time function in the forward function in `.cpp` or `.cu`, depending on you are using cpu or gpu.

or, the simplest way, using `caffe time`command